# eslint complaining about getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, eslint, next.js

This is my .eslintrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  "rules": {}
}
```

This is my component:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    ....
  }
}
```

Eslint is complaining about getInitialProps:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token getInitialProps
```

There is any way to make eslint accept getInitialProps declaration besides adding a suppress comment?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use babel-eslint due to the `static async`?

Comment: why is getInitialProps async?  this may be your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @Scott in the comments, the solution was to add [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint), my final .eslintrc was the following:

```
{
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  "rules": {}
}
```